# How to remove indent and also justify the text and avoid text going out of margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex

I want to add text in justified and without indent. Can someone help how to go further from this code. Also the text crosses the margin. How to stop it

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=8mm,right=8mm,top=8mm, bottom=8mm}

[17-20/44][1/6][1-2/2][23-26/50][4-7/12] 5x[16/16][1/1]

sometextsometextsometextsometextsometext sometextsometext

\end{document}
```

Below is the output

[image]

Comment: There is also \sloppy vs. \fussy.  (Default is \fussy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the indent you can remove by either placing `\noindent` in front of the line you want to have without it to **remove a parindent locally**

*or*

you place a `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` in your preamble to **disable parindents globally**.

Loading the `microtype`-package can also help in reducing `overfull hboxes`

Your code would then look like this:

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=8mm,right=8mm,top=8mm, bottom=8mm}

\noindent[17-20/44][1/6][1-2/2][23-26/50][4-7/12] 5x[16/16][1/1]

sometextsometextsometextsometextsometext sometextsometext

\end{document}
```

[image: noindent]

## Edit

The example given is not exactly fair, since in a regular text you wouldn't have to deal with words of such length (except if you're Welsh or German). You can always insert `\allowbreak` inside words if you want them to be broken without hyphenation:

```
\documentclass[paper=A7]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{left=8mm,right=8mm,top=8mm, bottom=8mm}

\noindent[17-20/44][1/6]\allowbreak [1-2/2][23-26/50]\allowbreak [4-\allowbreak7\allowbreak /12] 5x[16/16][1/1]

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: allowbreak]

Comment: `Loading the microtype-package can also help in reducing overfull hboxes`. This helps if the paper size is A6 but If i use A7  paper size, the text flows outside the margins.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi, please, be so kind to test my edit. Does this help?

Comment: Definitely. thank you

Comment: Re: \allowbreak. And if you want to give hyphenation points for strange non-words (or even some real words), insert `\-`.